# Fetching entities and filtering results

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to fetch entities that have an association with a field of a certain value. I can get all entities that pass that by doing something like,

```
$qb->select('e')
   ->from('AcmeBundle:Entity', 'e')
   ->join('e.association', 'a')
   ->where('a.field = :field')
   ->setParameter('field', $value);
```

As expected, the result of the query this builds would get me the Entities that have an association that passes that WHERE clause. As a part of this, I would like to be able to get partial entities that do not contain the associations that do not pass the clause. Is this something that is in the scope of Doctrine or will it be up to me in filter out the unwanted results in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Native queries](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-native-queries.html) ([Ref](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)).

You can write the native query and map the result set to the entities.

Comment: Can you provide a general example like I did in my question? I'm a little confused as how I actually limit the results returned by the join.

Comment: I am now able to limit the returned records for the JOIN through something along the lines of, JOIN artwork artwork ON(association.id = e.association_id). My problem now is that the associated entities are not always returned. 5 out of 7 results are returned without the association.

Comment: The key was Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder::addJoinedEntityResult()